# Working with HandlebarsJS and dynamic data

Tags: javascript, web-applications, handlebars.js

I'm using Handlebars.JS for a web-app and I'm not really sure how to get Handlebars to constantly update data when it changes.

Two specific questions here.

1. I'm using the {{#each}} block helper to iterate through a list. What is the best way to link a textbox to it which will filter the list and update the DOM whenever it is updated.
2. The data is periodically refreshed and pulled using AJAX. What is the best way to update the DOM with the new data when it arrives?

Thanks.